# Не считывается строка

Tags: c#, строки

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего он не считывает строку. Понятно, что исключение вываливается, но при этом почему-то он не выводит до исключения ничего. 
Причем работает с непонятным элементом мистики. Если содержимое файла 1.тхт всего две маленькие строчки, то он их вообще не выводит, а сразу дает эксепшн.
Если содержимое файла большой кусок текста (где-то страница на англ. языке), тогда выводит его без первого символа, а потом исключение.
Вот код:

```
static void Main()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    fs.Position = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но Вы допустили ошибку в пути к файлу. Слэш забыли.
Попробуйте D:\1.txt

Comment: Да, и правда. Исправил, но все равно все то же самое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BinaryReader` не предназначен для чтения текстовых файлов. Используйте класс `StreamReader`.

**UPDATE:** Прочитайте внимательно документацию к методу [`BinaryReader.ReadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring(v=vs.110).aspx).

Класс `BinaryReader` используется для чтения данных из бинарных файлов. Данный метод `ReadString()` подразумевает, что строка в байтовом потоке предваряется значением длины строки, которое закодировано как целое число блоками по семь битов.

В текстовых же файлах строки записываются c обозначением конца через символ перевода строки (`'\n'`, `'\r\n'`, `'\r'`, в зависимости от ОС или иных соглашений). Для чтения таких файлов существует класс [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Согласен, но все же на уровне системы этот файл состоит из бинарных данных, он должен хотя бы что-то вывести. Тем более, что если текст длинный, то он его весь выводит, кроме первой буквы, почему-то.